# OrderBy not working for ascending but works for descending

Tags: vue.js

I am making a Vue Webapp and need to sort data ascending or descending.
As per the code, everything should work fine

**template**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <h6 class="dropdown-header">Ascending</h6>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a @click="order('name','asc')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category</a>
          <a @click="order('catName','asc')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category</a>
          <a @click="order('subcatName','asc')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">SubCategory</a>
          <a @click="order('cocatName','asc')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">CoCategory</a>
          <a @click="order('uploadedAt','asc')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Uploaded At</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <h6 class="dropdown-header">Descending</h6>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a @click="order('name','desc')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category</a>
          <a @click="order('catName','desc')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Category</a>
          <a @click="order('subcatName','desc')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">SubCategory</a>
          <a @click="order('cocatName','desc')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">CoCategory</a>
          <a @click="order('uploadedAt','desc')" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Uploaded At</a>
        </div>
```

**Order method**

```
order(On, Way) {
      this.loading = true;
      //
      let newArray = [];
      this.orderItems = On;
      this.orderWay = Way;

      if ((this.orderWay = "desc")) {
        newArray = _.orderBy(this.items, this.orderItems, "desc");
      } else {
        newArray = _.orderBy(this.items, this.orderItems, "asc");
      }

      this.items = newArray;

      this.loading = false;
    }
```

Descending works perfectly fine.
But, in ascending too, it sort Z to A which is same as descending.
Can someone tell, Why and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `this.orderWay = "desc"` is not a valid comparison. Remember to use `===` to compare two variables.

`this.orderWay === "desc"`

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code by:

```js
order(On, Way) {
   this.loading = true;

   this.orderItems = On;
   this.orderWay = Way;

   this.items = _.orderBy(this.items, On, Way);

   this.loading = false;
}
```